# (CellIdentityLte) - how can I use it?

Tags: java, android, lte

I need to get PCI of LTE base station. 
There is a special class and method for it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityLte.html

But I'm a novice, and I have no idea how to use info given in developer.android. So, everything I tried is:

```
int i = CellIdentityLte.getPci();
```

How can I get this value?

Answer (score 0):

register for phonestate listener with this event(PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_INFO)

then u will be getting a method namely onCellInfoChanged called ..
inside that .. write this code..

```
for(Cellinfo m: info)
 if (m instanceof CellInfoLte){
                        CellInfoLte cellInfoLte=(CellInfoLte) m;
                        cellInfoLte.getCellIdentity().getPci();
                        Log.d("onCellInfoChanged", "CellInfoLte--" + m);
                    }
```